# Shell script, grep valid IP explanation

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I found this piece of code out on the internet and I would like to know how it works, think you can help me?

```
grep -E -o "(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)" file.txt
```

I understand grep -E and -o , I also understand that it greps a valid IP, but I don't understand how it does that, can you explain the different parts of the code?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for spoon fed information.

Comment: A little bit of searching would find you the answer... [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23412830/shell-script-grep-valid-ip-explanation]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?
```

This gives `250-255` or `200-249` or `0-199` so it covers numbers allowed in an IP address `0-255`
Then `\.` gives a `.`
Total i makes up an IP from `0.0.0.0` to `255.255.255.255`